# Structure Identification in HDL codes

Tags: vhdl, verilog, hdl, code-design

I wanted to automatically Identify some structures in HDL code (Verilog/VHDL), let say an adder. I need to automatically detect how many adders in the design. I am not sure from where to start, should I like convert my code into AST (abstract syntax tree) look for pattern and then convert it back to Verilog/HDL ? can anyone mention an example  or a small tutorial on how to do such tasks ?
Thanks

Comment: GHDL offers [something](http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/Simulation.html#cmdoption-ghdl-disp-tree) that might be useful to you. I can't say anything about how useful it is, I only used it once.

Comment: You can compile and check the rtl schematic of ur code. It will give you the digital blocks being implemented if that's what you meant by "structure"

Comment: Identifying adders is more complicated then just creating an AST or similar structure. You need to synthesize the HDL description. This means translate HDL into a schematic. Then you can identify structures in the schematic like adders. Can't you parse synthesis log files? These contain messages like signal xyz was translated to an adder.